# Dagger 2 multibindings with Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

I have the following snippet in my dagger 2 module

```
@Singleton
@Provides
@ElementsIntoSet
fun providesQueries(foo: Foo): Set<Foo>{
    val queries = LinkedHashSet<Foo>()
    queries.add(foo)
    return queries
}
```

I try to inject into in this way

```
@Inject lateinit var foo: Set<Foo>
```

But dagger shows an error which says that Dagger cannot provides java.util.Set without @Provides or @Produces method.

I did the same in java and it worked. Does somebody know why is it failing?

Comment: What annotation processor do you use?

Comment: I use kapt. I have the following lines in my build.gradle.      

kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$dagger_version"
kapt {
    generateStubs = true
}

Comment: Compare java generated classes and kotlin generated classes, see the diff. Obviously generated class misses @Produces.

Comment: No, the problem is that kapt fails into the translation and adds <? extends Foo> and dagger does not know how to manage that. I'm trying to have this module in java as a workarround.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

As it described in the Kotlin [reference](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html#variant-generics)

> To make Kotlin APIs work in Java we generate `Box<Super>` as 
>   `Box<? extends Super>` for covariantly defined `Box` (or `Foo<? super Bar>` for
>   contravariantly defined Foo) when it appears as a parameter.

You can use `@JvmSuppressWildcards` for avoiding it, just as following:

```
@Inject lateinit var foo: Set<@JvmSuppressWildcards Foo>
```

Comment: MutableSet<> could also be used

Comment: Jesus Christ, 2 wasted days! Why it's so painful... Thank you! If anyone like me is struggling with multibinding `Map` it's pretty much the same trick. Ex: `class MviViewModelFactory @Inject constructor(private val providers: Map<Class<out ViewModel>, @JvmSuppressWildcards Provider<ViewModel>>) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {`

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I would make some important addition, if you use a specific Qualifier, you have to put "field" in the annotation: "@field:MyQualifier". You don't need to do it if you use Dagger 2.25.2 version and above, AFAIK.

Comment: `@JvmSuppressWildcards`  ... This is just a horror for anyone new to dagger :D