# dagger @IntoSet not work in kotlin object?

Tags: kotlin, dagger-2

I used example in https://google.github.io/dagger/multibindings

Module A

```
@Module
object MyModuleA {
    @Provides
    @IntoSet
    fun provideOneString(): String {
        return "ABC"
    }
}
```

Module B

```
@Module
object MyModuleB {
    @Provides
    @ElementsIntoSet
    fun provideSomeStrings(): Set<String> {
        return HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList("DEF", "GHI"))
    }
}
```

component

```
@Component(modules = [ MyModuleA::class, MyModuleB::class])
interface MyComponent {
    fun strings(): Set<String>
}
```

test

```
@Test
fun testMyComponent() {
    val myComponent = DaggerMyComponent.builder().build()
    println("${myComponent.strings()}")
}
```

It show error with MyModuleA must be set, but changing module from object to class is work fine.

```
@Module
class MyModuleA {
    @Provides
    @IntoSet
    fun provideOneString(): String {
        return "ABC"
    }
}

@Module
class MyModuleB {
    @Provides
    @ElementsIntoSet
    fun provideSomeStrings(): Set<String> {
        return HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList("DEF", "GHI"))
    }
}
```

@IntoSet annotation is not work in kotlin object?

Comment: Try marking the functions in `object` modules with `@JvmStatic` and it should work

Comment: It works, and I take a look at builded code. Dagger seems to create instance of object, then Dagger get null.

Answer (score 10):

I ran into the same problem and this answer solved it for me.

[Dagger 2 multibindings with Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43141740/dagger-2-multibindings-with-kotlin)

In short, you need to use Set<@JvmSuppressWildcards String> intead, because of the way that  kotlin handles type variance in generics.